# Displaying repeated names from month list just once in excel (2010)

Tags: excel, indexing, row, formula, names

I have a **Leaves Table** on sheet 1 that has the following headers

**Column A = Months**  ;  **Column B = Names**  ; Column C = ...

Now on Sheet 2, I have a months data validation list in Cell H59.

**QUESTION:** When I select a particular month from the data validation list, all the names from the Leaves Table (Column B) should display without any of the names repeating.

**For Example:**

```
 January                 Alpha      
 January                 Alpha
 January                 Bravo
 February                Charlie
 February                Alpha
 March                   Bravo
 April                   Charlie
 May                     Bravo
 May                     Bravo
 May                     Charlie
 May                     Alpha
 May                     Alpha
```

When I select the month "MAY" I want the cells to display like below:

```
Bravo
Charlie
Alpha
```

And **NOT**

```
Bravo
Bravo
Charlie
Alpha
Alpha
```

Current **ARRAY** Formula (Displaying like the second option)

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(TeamLeaves[Name],SMALL(IF((TeamLeaves[Month]=Dashboard!$H$59),ROW(TeamLeaves[Month])-ROW(Leaves!$A$3)+1),ROWS(Leaves!$A$3:Leaves!$A3))),"")}
```

Please help! (No VBA)

Best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an approach that uses a *Helper column* that you can adapt to your needs.  We place your data in columns **A** and **B** and put the validation list cell in **E1**.

In **C1** enter:

```
=IF(A1<>$E$1,"",ROW())
```

and in **C2** enter:

```
=IF(A2<>$E$1,"",IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:A1=$E$1)*($B$1:B1=B2))>0,"",1+MAX($C$1:C1)))
```

and copy down.  Column **C** marks the items to be retrieved.

In **E2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$20,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),$C$1:$C$20,0)),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

This method avoids the array formula.

Comment: This is awesome Gary! It all works like I wanted but it's taking a beating on the aesthetics front. For example in the above screenshot, when I select January in E1 then E2 stays blank and E3 & E4 shows up Alpha and Bravo respectively. It's 11:30PM here and I will try fixing that over the weekend or so. But if you know why that's happening, then please help! Thanks a ton anyways!

Comment: @ZatinDharmapuri  I will review the equations and update the post if I find a problem! ..............Have A Great Weekend!!!

Comment: Appreciate that. You too have great weekend. Bye now!